# Add background thread that Vibrate's the phone when called

Tags: ios, multithreading, audio, vibration, iphone-vibrate

I take over the audio input to analyze what note is being played by an instrument.  That takes over a main thread.  **How do I create a thread to run with it so that when the note gets played on tune I can vibrate the phone?**

This is my `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self vibrate];

    pthread_t buf_update_thread;

    // Setup audio input
    CTAudioBuffer * audioInput = InitAudio(); // This is where will not allow vibrate

    animation = [[Animation alloc] init];

    [animation init:(UIView *) self.view];

    pthread_create(&buf_update_thread, NULL, &analyzeData, audioInput);

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:REDRAW_TIMER target:self selector:@selector(updateCTDisplay:) userInfo: nil repeats:YES];
}
```